# Dispatcher issue | “jcr:content” changed to “jcr%3acontent”

Tags: aem, dispatcher

We have recently faced a problem at dispatcher level wherein one of the ajax call which was getting some data form CQ repository had `“jcr:content”` in it and that got encoded to `“jcr%3acontent”` resulting in wrong result set.

Example:
http://x.x.x.x:4502/a/b/jcr:content/par/....

We have evaluated 2 possible solutions for this problem:

1. Can fix this on code level, wherein all request would get routed to a filter and that will make sure  “jcr%3acontent” get change to “jcr:content”

   Pros: this can quickly fix our existing problem

   Cons: there could be problems in future wherein other special characters can result in same problem
2. Due to problem with approach discussed in point#1, we have checked for some other solutions. After doing some research we have found that upgrading dispatcher version solved the issue. We are using CQ 5.6.1 with dispatcher version 4.1.5 and we upgraded dispatcher to 4.1.7.
   Now to support this we don’t have any documentation which suggests that this is known problem with dispatcher version 4.1.5

Does anybody in this community have faced this issue and if yes, then what was the solution applied for the same?

Also can somebody point me to the location where known dispatcher 4.1.5 issues are documented?

Comment: How about rewriting the ajax call to use "_jcr_content" instead? This will work as well and is a valid url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the observations on mentioned issue. I had following solutions proposed on different forums.

```
Solution 1
```

rewriting the ajax call to use "_jcr_content" instead on "jcr:content" as mentioned by @Thomas

```
Solution 2
```

Writing a CQ filter to make this check as mentioned by @viper

```
Solution 3
```

Adobe has also acknowledged this as dispatcher version issue and suggested to upgrade the version, I did that and it got fixed. FYI dispatcher version got upgraded from 4.1.15 to 4.1.17

Answer (score 1):

Please use ResourceResolver.map() method to get a 'Friendly'  URL to be used / issued get requests from and also to solve the caching issue with Dispatcher. 
The map() method encodes the ':'  colon to underscores and the resolve() method decodes them back to SLING JCR readable format.

You need to use the map() method to generate the URL that is used in the Ajax call.

Further read :  http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html#namespace-mangling